# anchor text url is not showing as link in th:text thymleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I converted some text to show as link, it's coming correctly from back-end but at UI it not shows as link.
I am using thymelaf to render the text inside p tag. Please find the code below:

html file:

```
 <div class="column" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" th:each="pre:${prrMap}"> 
     <div class="prerequisite" align="center">
              <label class="prerequisite" th:text="${pre.key}"></label>
              <p class="prerequisite" id="prerequisite" th:text=${pre.value}></p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**th:text=${pre.value}** contains the String having anchor text.

> Example: ${pre.value} = "prerequisite: Tesing data {a
>   href="https://ecom-test-data.index.html"}test link {/a} link created
>   data but not showing as link"

I cannot include anchor text tag here, so used {} = <>, It shows as it is at front-end.

> Excepted output: prerequisite: Testing data [test link](https://google.com) link
>   created data but not showing as link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `th:utext` (instead of `th:text`) if you wish to output unescaped html.

Comment: Thanks, it works but it's not working for new line. in dev tool it shows correct but in UI (chrome) it doesn't show the same. it has lot of problem converting String to look good in html.

Comment: If you want a newline, you have to use a `<br />`. Html doesn't preserve whitespace.